# Django and FasctCGI on Windows

Tags: django, windows-xp, fastcgi

sorry for making such bizarre question, but it seems that Windows and FastCGI for Django are not good friends; FastCGI will use Flup, and Flup hates windows! and when making

```
manage.py runfcgi
```

it will rise an error:

> can't import flup.server.scgi_fork

so is there any tip or trick to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry if it's me who will answer, but i found that windows dont support FastCGI, who wants this, get Linux :)

or try this http://pypi.python.org/pypi/fcgi-python/0.5